# python difflib comparing files

Tags: python, text, difflib

I am trying to use difflib to produce diff for two text files containing tweets. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# difflib_test

import difflib

file1 = open('/home/saad/Code/test/new_tweets', 'r')
file2 = open('/home/saad/PTITVProgs', 'r')

diff = difflib.context_diff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
delta = ''.join(diff)
print delta
```

Here is the `PTITVProgs` text file:

```
Watch PTI on April 6th (7) Dr Israr Shah at 10PM on Business Plus in "Talking Policy". Rgds #PTI
CORRECTION!! Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on ARY News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on AAJ News (6) PTI vs PMLN at 8PM on NewsOne. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) Asad Umar at 8PM on AAJ News (6) PTI vs PMLN at 8PM on NewsOne. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) Waleed Iqbal at 8PM on Channel 5. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (3) Dr Israr Shah at 10PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (4) Javed hashmi at 1PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (3) Imran Alvi at 1PM on AAJ News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (1) Dr @ArifAlvi, Andleeb Abbas and Ehtisham Ameer at 11PM on ARY News (2) Hamid Khan at 10PM on ATV. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 5th (1) Farooq Amjad Meer at 10:45PM on Dunya News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 4th (4) Faisal Khan at 8PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
@FaisalJavedKhan
Watch PTI on April 4th (3) Faisal Khan at 11PM on ATV. Rgds #PTI
@FaisalJavedKhan
Watch PTI on April 4th (1) Dr Israr Shah at 8PM on Waqt News (2) Dr Arif Alvi at 9PM on PTV World. Rgds #PTI
@ArifAlvi
Watch PTI on April 3rd (12) Abrar ul Haq on 10PM on Dawn News (13) Shabbir Sial at 10PM on Channel5. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (11) Sadaqat Abbasi on 8PM on RohiTV. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (10) Dr Zarqa and Andleeb Abbas on 8PM on Waqt News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (9) Fauzia Kasuri at 8PM on Din News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (8) Mehmood Rasheed at 8PM on ARY News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (7) Israr Abbasi (Repeat on Arp 4th) at 1:20AM and 1PM on Vibe TV. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (5) Rao Fahad at 9PM on Express News (6) Dr Seems Zia at 10:30PM on Health TV. Rgds #PTI
```

Here is the `new_tweets` text file:

```
Watch PTI on April 7th (3) Malaika Reza at 8PM on AAJ News (4) Shah Mehmood Qureshi at 8PM on Geo News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 7th (2) Chairman IMRAN KHAN at 10PM on PTV News in News Night with Sadia Afzal, Rpt: 2AM, 2PM. Rgds #PTI
@ImranKhanPTI
Watch PTI on April 7th (1) Dr Waseem Shahzad NOW at 6PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (7) Dr Israr Shah at 10PM on Business Plus in "Talking Policy". Rgds #PTI
CORRECTION!! Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on ARY News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on AAJ News (6) PTI vs PMLN at 8PM on NewsOne. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) Asad Umar at 8PM on AAJ News (6) PTI vs PMLN at 8PM on NewsOne. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (5) Waleed Iqbal at 8PM on Channel 5. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (3) Dr Israr Shah at 10PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (4) Javed hashmi at 1PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (3) Imran Alvi at 1PM on AAJ News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 6th (1) Dr @ArifAlvi, Andleeb Abbas and Ehtisham Ameer at 11PM on ARY News (2) Hamid Khan at 10PM on ATV. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 5th (1) Farooq Amjad Meer at 10:45PM on Dunya News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 4th (4) Faisal Khan at 8PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
@FaisalJavedKhan
Watch PTI on April 4th (3) Faisal Khan at 11PM on ATV. Rgds #PTI
@FaisalJavedKhan
Watch PTI on April 4th (1) Dr Israr Shah at 8PM on Waqt News (2) Dr Arif Alvi at 9PM on PTV World. Rgds #PTI
@ArifAlvi
Watch PTI on April 3rd (12) Abrar ul Haq on 10PM on Dawn News (13) Shabbir Sial at 10PM on Channel5. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (11) Sadaqat Abbasi on 8PM on RohiTV. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (10) Dr Zarqa and Andleeb Abbas on 8PM on Waqt News. Rgds #PTI
Watch PTI on April 3rd (9) Fauzia Kasuri at 8PM on Din News. Rgds #PTI
```

Here is the diff i get from the program:

```
*** 
--- 
***************
*** 1,7 ****
- Watch PTI on April 7th (3) Malaika Reza at 8PM on AAJ News (4) Shah Mehmood Qureshi at 8PM on Geo News. Rgds #PTI
- Watch PTI on April 7th (2) Chairman IMRAN KHAN at 10PM on PTV News in News Night with Sadia Afzal, Rpt: 2AM, 2PM. Rgds #PTI
- @ImranKhanPTI
- Watch PTI on April 7th (1) Dr Waseem Shahzad NOW at 6PM on PTV News. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 6th (7) Dr Israr Shah at 10PM on Business Plus in "Talking Policy". Rgds #PTI
  CORRECTION!! Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on ARY News. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 6th (5) @Asad_Umar  at 8PM on AAJ News (6) PTI vs PMLN at 8PM on NewsOne. Rgds #PTI
--- 1,3 ----
***************
*** 21,24 ****
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (12) Abrar ul Haq on 10PM on Dawn News (13) Shabbir Sial at 10PM on Channel5. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (11) Sadaqat Abbasi on 8PM on RohiTV. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (10) Dr Zarqa and Andleeb Abbas on 8PM on Waqt News. Rgds #PTI
! Watch PTI on April 3rd (9) Fauzia Kasuri at 8PM on Din News. Rgds #PTI--- 17,23 ----
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (12) Abrar ul Haq on 10PM on Dawn News (13) Shabbir Sial at 10PM on Channel5. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (11) Sadaqat Abbasi on 8PM on RohiTV. Rgds #PTI
  Watch PTI on April 3rd (10) Dr Zarqa and Andleeb Abbas on 8PM on Waqt News. Rgds #PTI
! Watch PTI on April 3rd (9) Fauzia Kasuri at 8PM on Din News. Rgds #PTI
! Watch PTI on April 3rd (8) Mehmood Rasheed at 8PM on ARY News. Rgds #PTI
! Watch PTI on April 3rd (7) Israr Abbasi (Repeat on Arp 4th) at 1:20AM and 1PM on Vibe TV. Rgds #PTI
! Watch PTI on April 3rd (5) Rao Fahad at 9PM on Express News (6) Dr Seems Zia at 10:30PM on Health TV. Rgds #PTI
```

As you can see by quickly comparing the two source files (PTITVProgs and new_tweets) that the difference between them are **the 3 tweets that were on April 7th** and **3 tweets on April 3rd**.

I just want the lines in `new_tweets` that are not in `PTITVProgs` to appear in the diff.

But it throws a bunch of text that I don't want to see. I don't know what `*** 1,7***` and `*** 1,3***` in the diff output stand for...? What is the proper way to get **only** the changed lines?

Comment: I'm not sure difflib is the right tool for the job you're trying to do at all -- it's a lot more work (algorithmically speaking) to generate a diff than to just do a set comparison. `print set(fileA.readlines()).difference(set(fileB.readlines()))`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just parse output of diff like this (change '- ' to '+ ' if needed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# difflib_test

import difflib

file1 = open('/home/saad/Code/test/new_tweets', 'r')
file2 = open('/home/saad/PTITVProgs', 'r')

diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
delta = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('- '))
print delta
```

Comment: It's so odd that difflib doesn't have a place with this info and instead we need to parse the output to get this info

Answer (score 22):

There are multiple diff styles and different functions exist for them in the `difflib` library. `unified_diff`, `ndiff` and `context_diff`.

If you don't want the line number summaries, `ndiff` function gives a Differ-style delta:

```
import difflib

f1 = '''1
2
3
4
5'''
f2 = '''1
3
4
5
6'''

diff = difflib.ndiff(f1,f2)

for l in diff:
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
  1
- 2          
  3          
  4          
  5   
+ 6
```

**EDIT:**

You could also parse the diff to extract only the changes if that's what you want:

```
>>>changes = [l for l in diff if l.startswith('+ ') or l.startswith('- ')]

>>>for c in changes:
       print(c)
>>>
- 2
+ 6
```

Comment: From how I read the question the OP doesn't want the context lines either. @gatto's answer above does a better job matching the format the OP wants.